# Unable to bind data from backend to Angular Material's mat-table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

Hi I'm learning Angular and Angular Material building a simple web page that return the data from my backend.
The backend is up and running while my Angular project gives me this warning that prevent me to access data:

```
Unresolved variable
```

Inside my `<td mat-cell></td>`.

This is my backend-api.service-ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Users } from './users';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

 export class BackendApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOrders(): Observable<Users[]> {
    return this.http.get<Users[]>('http://localhost:8085/orders')
  }
}
```

And this is my table.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendApiService } from '../services/backend-api.service';
import { Users } from '../services/users';
import {MatTableModule} from "@angular/material/table";

const ELEMENT_DATA: Users[] = []

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatTableModule
  ]
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  datasource = ELEMENT_DATA
  constructor(private service: BackendApiService) { }
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'surname', 'price', 'acquiredIn']
  ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getOrders().subscribe((data: Users[]) => {
      this.datasource = data
    })
  }
}
```

I think they're fine, my doubt is about datasource because inside my table.component.html i can't acces any field of my model.

this is a part of my table.component.html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="datasource" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table">
  
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

my element.id turns the error.

I paste also my users.ts:

```
import { JsonObject, JsonProperty } from "typescript-json-serializer";

@JsonObject()
export class Users {
    @JsonProperty('id')
    id!: number;
    @JsonProperty('name')
    name!: string;
    @JsonProperty('surname')
    surname!: string;
    @JsonProperty('price')
    price!: 45;
    @JsonProperty('acquiredIn')
    acquiredIn!: Date;
}
```

Comment: Would be great if you can share what is the response received in the snippet.

Comment: Do you have row template in your `table`?  See `3. Define the row templates` in [this page](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

Comment: Yes i have the row template. I don't receive any response, it is compiled succesfully, I only get the 'Unresolved variable' warning.